# Do I need to have a secondary index to improve a query?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

Lets say i have the following table

```
---------------------------------------
 ID   FOREIGN_KEY      TIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------
 1          1      2014-01-01 12:00:00
 2          2      2014-01-06 12:00:00
 3          2      2014-01-05 12:00:00
 4          1      2014-01-12 12:00:00
 5          3      2014-01-09 12:00:00
```

I run a query to get `FOREIGN_KEY=1` and `MAX(timestamp)`. This will return row with ID = 4 in the above table.

To give some context, there are only ever likely to be max 1000 duplicate foreign keys in the table each with a unique timestamp. There are likely to be many thousands of unique foreign keys on the foreign keys parent table.

My question is, if I have an index on the FOREIGN_KEY, is it worth also having one on the timestamp for this query?

I've assumed that when this query is run, the database first gets all the records matching the foreign key (this should be quick as its indexed) and then just does a linear search on the returned rows to find the max timestamp. Is this correct?

If yes, I see no point in indexing the timestamp column, as a linear search on max 1000 rows shouldn't take too long. Adding an index wouldn't improve the query much, but would consume additional storage.

Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: I think a compound index on (foreign_key,timestamp) will perform best.

Comment: Simple way to know: measure performance with current setup. Add the index. Measure performance in changed system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your assumptions are correct.
If the FOREIGN_KEY column does not repeat much, then the date index might be redundant.

Though just for sake of benchmarking, you can try both the indexing schemes.